# Image not showing in handmade page with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I'm using JavaScript to print a part of my web page with a logo and some text added to it.
My problem is that the image's place is shown but the image itself is not there!

```
    <script>
    function printdiv(printpage) {

        var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
        var footstr = "</body>";
        var logostr = "<div style=\"width: 100%; text-align: center; height: 50px;\"><div class=\"pull-right\"><img src=\"../Images/lionLogo.jpg\" width=\"50\" height=\"50\" /></div><div>some text</div></div>";

        var newstr = document.all.item(printpage).innerHTML;
        var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = headstr + logostr + newstr + footstr;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;

        $('#modalShowDetails').modal('hide');
        $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
        $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
        $('.fade').remove();

        return false;
    }


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create image element dynamically to load image into the DOM

```
    var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
    var footstr = "</body>";
    var logostr = "<div style=\"width: 100%; text-align: center; height: 50px;\"><div class=\"pull-right\"></div><div>some text</div></div>";

    var newstr = document.all.item(printpage).innerHTML;
    var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = headstr + logostr + newstr + footstr;


    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      $('.pull-right').append(img);
    };

    //use full image source path like
    //img.src  = 'https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-QEBhGh-wj2A/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAGNY/nogbhLrR0mc/photo.jpg';
    img.src = '../Images/lionLogo.jpg';
    img.width = "50";
    img.height = "50";

    //adding delay to load image
    setTimeout(function() {
       window.print();
       document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
    }, 2000);



    $('#modalShowDetails').modal('hide');
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
    $('.fade').remove();

    return false;
```

Comment: i did,it worked well when i commented window.print() & document.body.innerHTML = oldstr but my purpose of doing this is printing it and its not in print preview-@Shriyansh

Comment: you can try the updated answer. calling window.print() after inserting the image

Comment: I've tried this before,it has the same problem,i even added some delay before calling the window.print(),my text is there but steal the image is not working

Comment: try using the full image source path. because it works in my case